# App store submission, bundle name, provisoning profiles

Tags: iphone

I found this post which was helpful [Tips for a successful AppStore submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28551/tips-for-a-successful-appstore-submission), but had some more questions.

My Xcode project creates a Target.  Does this have anything to do with my app name?  Currently they do not match, but I didn't know if it mattered since iTunesConnect says you upload a zip of the binary.

I did not update my Bundle Display Name since it didn't sound like I needed to unless I was supporting other regions, but I updated the Bundle name to what I would like my App to be called.

I thought someone said that I needed to have my AppID that is in the iOS provisioning portal to match with the name of the app.  Two questions on how that works, if your AppID is "FindMyDog", but my Bundle Name is "Find My Dog", is that an issue because of the spacebars?  What do I need to do in order to fix that?  Do I need to create a new AppID of "Find My Dog", and add it to my Xcode provisioning portal?  If so, does that replace my old provisioning profile I was using to run my app on the device?  Does the Provisioning Profile, Bundle Name, and AppID all have to have the same name?  Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**.Bundle Name is not necessary to match with the AppID.

*For Ex*: My appId is FriendsChecker, But the bundle name is Friends.

http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/friendschecker/id484047075?mt=8